# Multiple linear regression in one graph

Tags: r, tidyverse, linear-regression

I would like to make a graph with 3 linear regression curves in different colors. For an example in the mtcars dataset, I want to plot `hp` against `disp` for each `cyl`inder group (e.g. 4, 6, 8) and plot the linear regression curves in one plot, how would I do that?

Also if it's possible I want a label for the `adj.r2`, `slope` and `p-value` for each linear regression in the top left corner.

Thanks!

Below is a graph I have made with the regression in three *separate* plots, which might help understand what I wish to do.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

formula <- y~x

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",formula = formula) +
  theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl, scales = "free")+
  stat_poly_eq(
    aes(label = paste(stat(adj.rr.label), stat(p.value.label), sep = "*\", \"*")),
    formula = formula, parse = TRUE,size=3)
```

Comment: if you use ```aes(..,col=factor(cyl))``` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answers my question!

Comment: Sure no problem, thanks.